# Is $F(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)\frac{\sin(xt)}{t}dt$ differentiable for $f\in L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Is $F(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)\frac{\sin(xt)}{t}dt$ differentiable for $f\in L^1$

The problem asks to show that $F$ is differentiable a.e, but I do not see why it would be a.e

By MVT and DCT (Leibniz rule) we get that $F'(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)cos(xt)dt$ everywhere. Is it not true? Also this would imply that $F$ is actually lipshitz as $F'(x)$ is bounded.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy the conditions to apply the derivation under the integral sign theorem, seem to be satisfied to me.

Comment: Try to show that $\left| \frac{\sin(x+h)t - \sin xt}{ht} - \cos xt \right| \to 0$ pointwise as $h \to 0$ and is uniformly bounded in $L^\infty$. Then DCT guarantees it is everywhere differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the difference quotient.

\begin{align*}
\left| \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h} \right| &\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left| \frac{f(t)}{ht} \right| \left| \sin((x+h)t) - \sin(xt) \right| \ dt \\
& \leq  \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left| \frac{f(t)}{ht} \right| \left| xt + ht - xt \right| \ dt \\
&\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} | f(t) | \ dt \\
&< \infty
\end{align*}

where we used that $|\sin x - \sin y| \leq |x - y|$ for each $x, y$ (the sine is Lipschitz). The difference quotient is bounded. Now let $h = \frac{1}{n},$ and define $F_n(x) = |n (F(x + \frac{1}{n}) - F(x))|$. Then the sequence is bounded, and by the Dominated Convergence Theorem, the limit exists. Thus $F$ is a.e. differentiable.

Comment: How is $|\sin((x+h)t)-\sin(xt)|$ less than $ht$?  Your bound $|\sin(x)|\le x$ is correct.  But you have the difference of two sine functions.

Comment: Missed that. It should be by the Lipschitz property of sine.

Comment: Just use the prosthapharesis relationship for $\sin(a)-\sin(b)$.  You'll see that your bound works.

Comment: (+1) Yes.  The DCT guarantees that the limit can be interchanged with the integral.  And that is that.

Comment: @SeanRoberson My question is, why is it a.e and not everywhere?

Comment: @2132123 The function $f$ is Lebesgue integrable so we use that integral which ignores sets of measure zero. We don't have enough information (maybe?) to show differentibility everywhere.